# about malloc() : writing outside of allocated memory

Tags: c, malloc

I just noticed this and was wondering if there was a way to prevent it,

I am taking in an integer from the user, and then using the integer to allocate an array size, something like:

```
int main(void){
    int num;
    int *array;
    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    array = malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
    array[100]=123
    printf("%d",array[100]);
}
```

If input 4 for the number during runtime I am still able to print the value at array[100]. This is not what I want, is there a better way to dynamically allocate and prevent this problem. I feel like this may result in overflow issues if I make a mistake later on in my code

Comment: "_This is not what I want_" What do you want then? How do you want to prevent this "problem"?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking exactly.  Is it a bug to try to access `array[100]` if you've allocated less than 101 elements for `array`?  Yes, of course it is.  Don't do it.  I'm not sure why you're using a fixed index of 100, but if you feel you must, then make sure `num` is at least 101 or you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: If you want the language to avoid shooting yourself in your foot, definitively do not use C!

Comment: Did you do any research on yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Testing before reading or writing will do the trick.   In your case - noting that either reading or writing to an array using an invalid index gives undefined behaviour

```
 if (num > 100)
 {
     array[100]=123;
     printf("%d",array[100]);
 }
```

But, if you don't explicitly do something to ensure an index is valid (I've used the `num > 100` test to illustrate, but there are other ways to do it), then there is nothing in C to prevent invalid access to array elements - regardless of whether they were dynamically allocated using `malloc()` or not.

If you want such a safety net to be provided fo you (i.e. you don't want to bother with any effort to ensure array indices you use are valid, and expect the language/compiler/host machine to sort out the problem for you) then you will need a language other than C.

Also, you might want to check if `num` is positive, as `malloc()` will give unexpected results if it is zero or negative.  Similarly, `malloc()` returns `NULL` if it fails, and you should check the pointer returned BEFORE using it, not rely it being valid.

Answer (score 1):

Just add simple If statement. To prevent oveflow.

```
if(num>100)
  array[100]=123;
  printf("%d",array[100]);
else
{
  // what else you want to be done
}
```

Be careful!
Arrays always start from `array[0]` element. So if you allocate `ptrArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);`it will allocates an array of 100 elements from 0 to 99. The element `array[100]` in this context will be already an overflow and may cause undefined behaviour - which is not good duh :)

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better way to dynamically allocate and prevent this problem

No.

Simply don't write `array[100]=` if you don't know whether 100 is a  valid index.